# When $ a^5 < 5 $ show that there exists b such that $ a<b, b^5<5 $

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, real-numbers

Here's my approach.

Since $ a^5 < 5, a<\sqrt[5]{5} $

By density of rational number, there must be integer $m$ and natural number $n$ such that

$ a< \frac{m}{n} < \sqrt[5]{5}$

If I let $b= \frac{m}{n} $,   then $ a<b$ and $ b<\sqrt[5]{5} $

Since, $ b< \sqrt[5]{5}$, $ b^5 < 5 $,
therefore there exists $b$ such that $a<b$ and $b^5<5$

Is there anything that I should fix or add?
I wonder if I have to show that there exists real number $a$ such that $a^5<5$.

Comment: I need to show this using the fact between any two real numbers there is a rational number. Does it look bad?

Comment: I think that this proof is ok, but don't take my words for granted.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: No, you would not have to show the existence of such an $a$. However, depending on the stage at which this exercise is given, maybe you cannot assume that $\sqrt[5]{5}$ exists. For the above is often an exercise that is done when showing that the $n^{\text{th}}$ of a positive number exists. You may also have to justify why $a^5 < 5$ implies $a < \sqrt[5]{5}$. Other than that, the proof looks OK.

Comment: Thank you all! !

Comment: Does the problem specify that $a, b$ are positive rationals? If that's the case then the problem is interesting and non-trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $b=\frac{a+\sqrt[5]5}{2}.$

Thus, since $a<\sqrt[5]5,$ we see that $$b<\frac{\sqrt[5]5+\sqrt[5]5}{2}=\sqrt[5]5,$$ which gives $$b^5<5.$$

Also, $$b-a=\frac{a+\sqrt[5]5}{2}-a=\frac{\sqrt[5]5-a}{2}>0,$$ which says $a<b$.